# R plot multiple charts to single pdf using loop

Tags: r, loops, ggplot2

I have a single dataset that I am trying to filter multiple ways and in order to plot a number of graphs and save them to a single multichart pdf. To start I have tried the following:

```
pdf("LB_plus_UB_plots_3_problems_osc_10.pdf")
for (i in 1:10) {
  ggplot(data=dataset,aes(x=glim_f,y=LB,colour=state))+geom_line()+geom_line(aes(glim_f,UB,colour=state),dataset)
}

dev.off()
```

which is producing a single blank pdf. Strangely when I execute the lines individually, it produces the pdf as I want it with 10 parts. Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't see the iterator i being used inside the loop...

Comment: also I think you have to use `p=ggplot(...) print(p)` inside the loop